# Android studio close keyboard and finish activity

Tags: android, android-layout

When I open this activity, it shows the `EditText` and the soft keyboard automatically shows up.

I want the activity finished when I tap on the back button on the left down corner, not just close the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: add this in your activity in your manifest file  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in you utils to open the keyboard

```
  /**
 * Method to show keyboard
 *
 * @param context Context of the calling activity
 */
public static void showKeyboard(Context context) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Method to show keyboard
 *
 * @param context  Context of the calling activity
 * @param editText Edittext which will receive focus
 */
public static void showKeyboard(Context context, EditText editText) {
    showKeyboard(context);
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        imm.showSoftInput(((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also if you want to hide the keyboard then you can use this code :

```
 /**
 * Method to hide keyboard
 *
 * @param mContext Context of the calling class
 */
public static void hideKeyboard(Context mContext) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((Activity) mContext).getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Use this code in you menifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question i understand that you want to finish your activity on button click. For finish any activity you can use this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,Here is your first activity.Class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your activity

```
@Override 

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 

if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
 finish();
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```